# Comparison of groups over time using glm

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, treatment-effect, spatio-temporal

I have count data on three groups of sites, sampled annually over 6 years.

Group1 = target group

Group2= control (untreated group) and

Group3 = treated group (started the same as Group2).

My hypothesis is that OVER TIME Group3 will become less like Group2 and more like Group1.
I want to show in which year this occurs:

**Example result:**

**In year 1, Group3 is NS from Group2 but is sig dif from Group1. But in year 3,  Group3 is sig dif from Group2 and NS from Group1.)**

So how do I test for significance between all groups, with year as an interaction? 
Since Im comparing both Group1 and 2 to Group3, I thought to use Group3 as the reference (i.e. intercept) and Group1 and 2 as the independent 'treatments' using a poisson glm regression :

```
glm(count ~ group * year, dat ,family ="poisson")
```

If I set year as a factor will this test each group_year combo as a categorical interaction? (note the 6 years are not continuous: 2010:2013,2016,2017)

Is this the best way to test for differences between groups or is there a more elegant way? 
(note Im not particularly interested in the difference between groups 1 and 2, more in the transition of group 3).

Answer (score 0):

To get the type of result shown in your example (**e.g. In year 1, Group3 is NS from Group2 but is sig dif from Group1. But in year 3, Group3 is sig dif from Group2 and NS from Group1**) could you not just remove year from the model, and carry out separate tests for each year?

For example, subset your data into different years (dat_2010, dat_2011 etc), and use the formula

```
glm(count ~ group, dat_2010, family="poisson")
```

etc....

If you relevel your "group" variable so that Group 3 is the reference group that should give you the desired results - telling you whether Groups 1 and 2 differ significantly from Group 3 for each year of your experiment.